# I can't configure dbus due to expat

Tags: linux, arm

I'm crosscompiling bluez to my board and I can't compile dbus.

While configuring, this error message comes up:

```
checking for XML_ParserCreate_MM in -lexpat... no

configure: error: Explicitly requested expat but expat not found
```

So I re-installed expat several times, it worked, though with some warnings.
Please anybody give me any hint!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and was able to solve it by following the link: [Cross Compiling BlueZ Bluetooth tools for ARM](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_BlueZ_Bluetooth_tools_for_ARM). Below, I have copied the part which install expat.

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/files/expat/2.1.0/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf expat-2.1.0.tar.gz 
cd expat-2.1.0/
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross-compiled(for your platform) expat-2.1.0.tar.gz as mentioned by @AqeelArshad.
Once it compile success then link the lib path as well as include properly before performing ./configure <> <> <>. For example in my case cross-compiled lib is present under "/home/expat-2.1.0/my_build/lib" and headerfile "/home/expat-2.1.0/my_build/include/" respectively. It should work for you.

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I/home/expat-2.1.0/my_build/include/'
export CFLAGS='-I/home/expat-2.1.0/my_build/include/'
export LDFLAGS='-L/home/expat-2.1.0/my_build/lib'
```